# Sonata Admin - Adding a custom button in form field for collection type

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, sonata-admin

I have two relations oneToMany made in symfony and I wanted to know if there is anyway to add a custom button in the first entity (parent) to point to childs edit page.

Lets me explain a little more if needed.

When i set sonata_type_collection in this relation i get child properties to edit inline, which is great. The issue I have is that this child entity
has another child type sonata_type_collection and the way sonata admin shows this child is not the best way to edit it. So, I was thinking in inserting a
button in this place to edit this entity and see its childs entities. But i can't figure out how to do this.

I tryed to use 'button' type for achieve this, but I get the following error:

The options "label_render", "property_path", "sonata_field_description" do not exist. Defined options are: "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "disabled", "label", "label_format", "translation_domain".

Anyone knows how to do this?

**EDIT 1**

I have 3 classes with relations oneToMany:

let's say 'Establishment', 'SecEstablishment' and 'FlatSecEstablishment'. A establishmente can have cero or more SecEstablishments and a SecEstablishment can have one or more FlatSecEstablishments. Hope this code can help to understand what I need to do.

class EstablishmentControllerAdmin extends AbstractAdmin {

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->with('Details')
                    ->add('id','text', array('label' => 'Id', 'disabled' => true))
                    ->add('establishment', 'text', array ('label' => 'establishment'))
                    ->add('address', 'text', array('label' => 'Address', 'required' => false))
                    ->add('phone', 'text', array('label' => 'Phone', 'required' => false))
                    ->add('postalCode', 'integer', array('label' => 'Postal Code', 'required' => false))
               ->end()

            ->with('Establishment sectors')
                ->add('sectores','sonata_type_collection', 
                    array(
                        'btn_add' => 'New Sector',
                        'type_options' => array('delete' => false)
                    ), 
                    array(
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'table'
                    ))
            ->end();

}
```

}

class SecEstablishmentControllerAdmin extends AbstractAdmin {

```
protected $parentAssociationMapping = 'establishment';

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {

    if($this->hasParentFieldDescription()) {
    $formMapper
            ->with('Details')
                ->add('detSec', 'text')
                ->add('flatStructure', 'sonata_type_model', array(

                        'btn_list' => 'Select',
                        'btn_add' => false,
                        'btn_delete' => false,
                        'required' => false
                      ), array(
                          'placeholder' => 'Select Flat Structure',
                          'nullable' => true,
                      ))
            ->end();
    } else {
        $formMapper
            ->with('Details')
                ->add('flatStructure', 'sonata_type_model', array(

                        'btn_list' => 'Select',
                        'btn_add' => false,
                        'btn_delete' => false,
                        'required' => false
                      ), array(
                          'placeholder' => 'Select Flat Structure',
                          'nullable' => true,
                      ))
                ->add('secFlat','sonata_type_collection', 
                    array(
                         'btn_add' => false,
                         'type_options' => array('delete' => false)
                     ), 
                     array(
                         'edit' => 'inline',
                         'inline' => 'table'
                     ))
                ->end();
    }
}
```

}

class FlatSecEstablishmentControllerAdmin extends AbstractAdmin {

```
protected $parentAssociationMapping = 'secEstablishment';

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $formMapper
        ->with('Details')
            ->add('detFlat', 'text', array('label' => 'Flat Detail'))
        ->end();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question including the admin code I'm working on. Please, tell me if you need any other info.

Comment: any answer for this?